# Iodometric titration

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

When you carry out iodometric titration for determining the Peroxide value of a phospholipid mixture, the end point is the solution turning colourless. But, after some time the colour reappears. Do you stop at the first discoloration or continue titrating with sodium thiosulphate?

Comment: After how long the color re-appears?

Comment: It takes little more than about 5 mins

Comment: As per the American Oil Chemists’ Society (AOCS) Recommended Official Method Cd 8-53."The mixture is titrated with 0.1M sodium thiosulfate solution with constant stirring until the yellow colour has almost disappeared, when a starch indicator solution (0.5 mL) is added. The thiosulfate solution is added drop-wise until the blue colour just disappears." Make sure you do a blank as well, and it is clear that first disappearance marks the end point.

Comment: It has been a while, but I think that the appearance of the color again is due to oxygen in the air reacting with iodide to make iodine. If I'm wrong some one will surely nail me on that point. It has been 50 years since I did such titrations in quant. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, it is the same AOCS Method we are following. The method says stop titration till the colour disappears. But a colleague is doing it till the reappeared colour disappears , so his values are always higher. Where can I get the reaction of oxygen (from air) reacting with the iodide?

Comment: You have to do a blank titration as well as recommended by AOCS. Iodide is quite *slowly* oxidized by air in water but what happens in the presence of chloroform and acetic acid and some water, I don't know. Change the batch of both reagents and see if this happens again. If the blue color reappears in the blank after 5 min as you observe, then ignore the second reappearance.

Comment: Oh Okay. Will do that . BTW, I am taking blank. Thank you

Comment: Check if the blue color appears in the blank too.